# formula field to display flag

Tags: apex, formula-field

I am trying to display a  green flag when Account status__c(status__c is a picklist field) is Active, else display red flag. I have written below in formula field, but I am getting error message as "Error: Field status__c is a picklist field. Picklist fields are only supported in certain functions". Please help.

```
IMAGE( 
Account( status__c, 
"Yes", "/img/samples/flag_green.gif",
"/img/samples/flag_red.gif" ), 
"Status Flag")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot get value of the picklist field directly, you need to convert it into text first. Below code should work for you.

```
if(
  TEXT(status__c) == 'Yes',
  IMAGE("/img/samples/flag_green.gif", "Status Flag"),
  IMAGE("/img/samples/flag_red.gif", "Status Flag")
)
```

Comment: I would like to do this in apex as  if(acc.status__c == 'Yes'){
   acc.status__c = '/img/samples/flag_green.gif' + acc.status__c;
  }

Comment: Is it possible ?

Comment: Nope, why you want to go for apex if you can do this with the formula field?